# !HEROKU: [remote rejected] master -> master (pre-receive hook declined) error: failed to push some refs

Tags: node.js, heroku, npm

I've been trying to trouble shoot this for a while and just don't know what to do next aside from rebuilding my app from scratch. When I try and deploy to heroku, I keep getting the error below. I've build another app using the same steps and it uploaded fine, but for some reason this one is giving me an error I've never seen before. I've looked at other stackoverflow questions on this topic and they all request the build logs, so here it is below. Any ideas?

Thanks for any help!!

```
-----> Build
       Running heroku-postbuild

       > goals-against-united@1.0.0 heroku-postbuild /tmp/build_6320c60ef6ee13062fee2194118bc2df
       > NPM_CONFIG_PRODUCTION=false npm install --prefix client && npm run build --prefix client

       up to date in 0.282s
       found 0 vulnerabilities

npm ERR! code ENOENT
npm ERR! syscall open
npm ERR! path /tmp/build_6320c60ef6ee13062fee2194118bc2df/client/package.json
npm ERR! errno -2
npm ERR! enoent ENOENT: no such file or directory, open '/tmp/build_6320c60ef6ee13062fee2194118bc2df/client/package.json'
npm ERR! enoent This is related to npm not being able to find a file.
npm ERR! enoent 
npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /tmp/npmcache.fwONU/_logs/2020-03-31T20_51_10_439Z-debug.log
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 254
npm ERR! goals-against-united@1.0.0 heroku-postbuild: `NPM_CONFIG_PRODUCTION=false npm install --prefix client && npm run build --prefix client`
npm ERR! Exit status 254
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Failed at the goals-against-united@1.0.0 heroku-postbuild script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.
npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /tmp/npmcache.fwONU/_logs/2020-03-31T20_51_10_459Z-debug.log
-----> Build failed

       We're sorry this build is failing! You can troubleshoot common issues here:
       https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/troubleshooting-node-deploys

       Some possible problems:

       - node_modules checked into source control
         https://blog.heroku.com/node-habits-2016#9-only-git-the-important-bits

       Love,
       Heroku

 !     Push rejected, failed to compile Node.js app.
 !     Push failed
```

Comment: Your `client` folder does not have a `package.json`

Comment: It does before I push to heroku though? Why would it ignore package.json? It's not listed in my .gitignore either

Comment: Problem solved: it was an issue in most of my app not getting tracked by git. I had to create a new branch and then merge it with the master.